# Converting char to unsigned short in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, struct

I've been having some trouble saving `char` values into a structure field which is of the type `unsigned short`.

---EDIT: Here's the input .pgm ---

```
P2
6 10

255

255 255 255 255 10 255

255 255 255 255 20 255

255 255 255 255 30 255

255 255 255 255 40 255

255 255 255 255 50 255

255 255 255 255 60 255

110 255 255 255 70 255

255 100 90 80 255 255

255 255 255 255 255 255

255 255 255 255 255 255
```

So we're suppose to save a matrix composed of 0's and 1's, or other numbers. The structures are as follows:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned short rgb[3];   
}PIXEL_T;

typedef struct{
    int format;
    int nrows;
    int ncolumns;
    int max_color;
    PIXEL_T **pixels;   
}PBM_T;
```

And here's the code to save the 1 or 0 chars into the appropriate structure field.

```
void pbmMatrixASCII(char* line, size_t len, FILE* file_stream, PBM_T *img_struct) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
        char *token;

    while(getline(&line, &len, file_stream) != EOF) {
        token = strtok(line, " \n\t");
        while (token != NULL) {
            //DEBUG("%s", token);
            img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0] = strtol(token, NULL, 0);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
            printf("%hu ", img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");   
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now this works great for 0's and 1's. Problem is, when we have to save a matrix which has values ranging from 1 to 255. It saves and prints garbage. And we tried several casting methods. For example:

```
img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0] = (unsigned short) token;
```

They don't work. How can we fix this? (Also, is there a PROPER way to actually convert the values, one that serves for both problems?)

----EDIT in response to some feedback----

We're reading from pbm and pgm files. The second line of which is the size of the matrix, which we then read to the `img_struct->nrows` and `img_struct->ncolumns`. Here's the code:

```
//Detects the filetype and reads the matrix size (also reads max color in case of pgm)

//Reads the first line to determine the magic number    

    getline(&line, &len, file_stream);
    sscanf(line, "P%d", &aux_format);

    //Verifies if the format is valid. Exits if not

    if(aux_format > 6 || aux_format < 1) {
        ERROR(ERR_FORMAT,"Invalid format\n");
    }

    img_struct->format = aux_format; //Saves the format into the structure, after being verified

    int size_is_read = 0; //Variable used to verify if the size has been read (a makeshift boolean)

        while(getline(&line, &len, file_stream) != EOF){

            if (hasCommentsOrEmptyLines(line))
                continue;

    //Reads the size of the matrix

            if(size_is_read == 0) {
                sscanf(line,"%d %d",&columns,&rows);
                size_is_read = 1;
            }

            if(img_struct->format == 1 || img_struct->format == 4) { //P1 and P4 are .pbm files and therefore don't have  a maximum colour field
                break;

            } else if(img_struct->format == 2 || img_struct->format == 5){ //Every other file type needs to have its maximum colour field read

                while(getline(&line, &len, file_stream) != EOF) {

                    if(hasCommentsOrEmptyLines(line))
                        continue;

    //reads the max color                   
                    sscanf(line,"%d",&(img_struct->max_color));

                break;
            }

        }
        break;
    }
```

And after that, the memory alloc followed by the matrix reader function call (see above):

```
//Save the image size in the appropriate structure fields   
img_struct->nrows = rows;
img_struct->ncolumns = columns;

//Allocates the appropriate size of the matrix to save the bitmap

img_struct->pixels = MALLOC(sizeof(PIXEL_T *)*rows);
if (img_struct->pixels == NULL)
    ERROR(ERR_ALLOC,"Error allocating memory for the bitmap matrix");

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    img_struct->pixels[i] = MALLOC(sizeof(PIXEL_T)*columns);
}


//Iterate each position of the line array and convert it to an unsigned short 

switch(img_struct->format) {

    case 1:
        pbmMatrixASCII(line, len, file_stream, img_struct);
    break;

    case 2:
        printf("teste\n");
        pgmMatrixASCII(line, len, file_stream, img_struct);
    break;
```

Comment: Has img_struct->pixels been properly allocated? Your print statement after the assignment could be very misleading. The data may not be going where you think it is.

Comment: Will edit with more code.

Comment: Also, be sure you have all compiler warnings turned on and are not ignoring any of them.

Comment: Hmmm: `img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[1] img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[2]` are not used.  Results of `strtol()` that do not fit is an `unsigned short` are quietly lost.

Comment: The alloc looks ok. What is going on with j?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot used an unsigned char?

Comment: also prints garbage. it's strange how it works well with saving 1's and 0's, but 255's and etc just screws up.

Comment: What kind of garbage do you get? It's much more easy to spot where an error comes from when the symptoms are precisely known. But, please, try fixing the missing `j = 0` first...

Comment: @chux the [1] [2] positions are reserved for a third filetype, ppm, which will store triplets, each corresponding to an rgb colour. we just want to copy the file matrix to our own pixel matrix, which has to be unsigned short

Comment: @cmaster it just prints wrong values. this is the file matrix we wish to save: 255 255 255 255 10 255
255 255 255 255 20 255
255 255 255 255 30 255
255 255 255 255 40 255
255 255 255 255 50 255
255 255 255 255 60 255
110 255 255 255 70 255
255 100 90 80 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255

and this is the output:

164 168 172 179 0
//similar down here until the end

Comment: @Digriz Have you tried `j = 0;` _after_ the `getline()` yet?

Comment: Yes, still core dumps.

Comment: Is line initialized somewhere like `char *line = NULL;`?

Comment: @chux yes, the pointer is initialized as null in the "common.c" file. It's then passed as a parameter to the pgmMatrixASCII function, which is in another .c file
I also thought it might have been wrong pointer usage, but the .pbm file (0's and 1's matrix) reads and saves fine...

Comment: Opening `file_stream` as a binary file?  ("r" or "rb")?

Comment: We're opening the stream with "r" since we're dealing with ASCII here. We also have to handle binary files at some point though. Should it be rb for both?

Comment: @Digriz  If you are using binary, your tokens `" \n\t"` may need to expand to `" \n\t\r"`.  Other side affects are possible as you are using a C string and text routines.  Just trying to help with ideas as I do not see the crux of the problem yet.

Comment: I appreciate the input guys. Still core dumps. I have no clue why. Alleyoop says the coredump has something to do with strtol though.
About to quit this whole developer business ahah...

Comment: strange... like this http://pastebin.com/THUKwuku
the function prints right. is is the strtok, or maybe we should free every pointer in the main.c?

Comment: @Digriz Please verify: With `pgmMatrixASCII(line, len...`, you are calling with _supposedly_ a `char*` and `size_t`.  Inside `pgmMatrixASCII()` you call `getline(...&len)`  This updates the _local_ copy of the size and affects the global `line`.  But these 2 need to work together.  Suggest use a local `line` and `len`, do not pass them in to `pgmMatrixASCII()`.  GTG

Comment: @chux it's a bit tricky, because we're working on a filestream, and we're actually counting on the getline pointer as it is passed. if we work with a local getline pointer, we'd need to find the matrix, while ignoring each previous line in the file. Which is already done in common.c, and it's a bit hard to redo, since there's no global condition for when a line has the matrix (each matrix is different in each file)

Comment: @Digriz OK, so skip the local bit.  Think of what `getline()` is doing in `pgmMatrixASCII()`.  It is updating `line` and `len`, but when `pgmMatrixASCII()` returns, the higher level `line` and `len` are _not_ updated and their values are _no longer valid_.  Any subsequent use would lead to UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using C functions for tokenizing the string, try simply iterating through it like so:

```
void pbmMatrixASCII(char* line, size_t len, FILE* file_stream, PBM_T *img_struct) {
    int i = 0;

    while(getline(&line, &len, file_stream) != EOF) {
        // Extract all pixel entries.
        int nFound = getPixels(line, img_struct->ncolumns, img_struct->pixels[i]);

        // Print out what we found.
        // int j = 0;
        // for (j = 0; j < nFound; j++) {
        //     printf("%hu %s",
        //         img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0],
        //         ((j + 1) == nFound ? "\n": ""));
        // }

        // Go to the next row of pixels if we found values.
        if (nFound == img_struct->ncolumns)
            i++;
    }
}
```

And have another function parse each line you read in:

```
int getPixels(char * line, int numExpected, PIXEL_T * pixelRow) {
    int max                = strlen(line);
    int counter            = 0;
    PIXEL_T * currentPixel = pixelRow;
    char * linePtr         = line;

    while (counter < numExpected) {
        // Reach the first non-whitespace character.
        while (linePtr[0] == ' ') {
            if ((linePtr - line) >= max)
                return (counter);

            linePtr++;
        }

        if (linePtr[0] == '\n')
            return (counter);

        // Grab the unsigned short value.
        int numFound = sscanf(linePtr, "%hu", &currentPixel->rgb[0]);

        // Make sure we found something.
        if (numFound > 0)
            currentPixel++, counter++;
        // Error happened with sscanf! Return what we found so far.
        else if (numFound < 0)
            return (counter);

        // Reach the first non-NON-whitespace character. Double negative ;)
        while (linePtr[0] != ' ') {
            if ((linePtr - line) >= max)
                return (counter);

            linePtr++;
        }
    }
    return (counter);
}
```

This way, you never have to actually cast the value from a character; it's read as an unsigned short by sscanf(...).

-- EDIT: The following is for reading from PPM files --

Note: `numExpected` is the number of expected RGB *triplets* you'll see. Passing in a value of 2 means there should be 2 pixels there, each with 3 values, totaling to 6 actual entries on the line read in. This corresponds to the width value in the top part of the PPM file, itself.

```
int getPixels(char * line, int numExpected, PIXEL_T * pixelRow) {
    int max                = strlen(line);
    int counter            = 0;
    int currentValue       = 0;
    PIXEL_T * currentPixel = pixelRow;
    char * linePtr         = line;

    while (counter < numExpected) {
        while (currentValue < 3) {
            // Reach the first non-whitespace character.
            while (linePtr[0] == ' ') {
                if ((linePtr - line) >= max)
                    return (counter);

                linePtr++;
            }

            if (linePtr[0] == '\n') {
                return (counter);
            }

            // Grab the unsigned short value.
            int numFound = sscanf(linePtr, "%hu", &currentPixel->rgb[currentValue]);

            // Make sure we found something.
            if (numFound == 1)
                currentValue++;

            // Error happened with sscanf! Return what we found so far.
            else if (numFound < 0)
                return (counter);

            // Reach the first non-NON-whitespace character. Double negative ;)
            while (linePtr[0] != ' ') {
                if ((linePtr - line) >= max)
                    return (currentValue == 3 ? counter + 1 : counter);

                linePtr++;
            }
        }

        counter++, currentPixel++, currentValue = 0;
    }
    return (counter);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution! Any insight on how the getPixels code should be?

Comment: I'm so stupid, I misnamed the function in the second part of my post, going to edit it now hahahaha.

Comment: ah, I had a feeling the second function was the getPixels
Thanks a lot, will try and give feedback.

Comment: Just FYI, I changed code in the `getPixels(...)` function to make sure `numFound` is greater than zero, as `sscanf(...)` could return EOF on a failure.

Comment: You sir, are awesome.
I now learned to never trust header functions when you just have to do it yourself.
If you want something done right....
Kudos mate, I'd upvote, but there's not enough privilege yet :p
Thanks for helping this poor noob!

Comment: No worries! Before you marked my response as an answer I couldn't upvote your question! hahaha #happycoding :)

Comment: To update pointer, could use `int n = 0; int numFound = sscanf(linePtr, "%hu%n", &currentPixel->rgb[0], &n); ... linePtr += n;`

Comment: This is true! The while loop following the `numFound` check would be redundant then, seeing as how `sscanf(...)` is capable of doing this for us. Will update code accordingly.

Comment: Might want to change `else if (numFound < 0)` to `else`.  Otherwise should `numFound == 0`, you may never exit the loop.

Comment: Actually just changed it back, the conversion length %n integer pointer is only updated if something is found, therefore the string "1 2 3 abc 4" would only find "1 2 3" and stop instead of "1 2 3 4" while ignoring non-numbered characters in the string.

Comment: @datboi, True about %n.  but if `numFound` is <= 0, you should exist the loop anyways, so `n` is set when it needs to be set.  Anyways - it was an idea for your consideration.

Comment: @chux: If numFound is exactly zero that just means no match was found, but what is unknown is whether more data exists past this unrecognizable string of chars. I feel that the loop should only exit from sscanf(...) if an error is encountered, as a single non-numeric entry would stop your whole loop from parsing further values if you only used the %n instead of another loop. This is why I only exit if < 0 in the above code; the string "abc 1 2 3 4 5" would find no values solely using %n.

Comment: @datboi We appear to agree on what to do if data is well formed.  We differ on handling of unusual input strings.  As this detail is beyond the post, any well thought out approach suffices for these answers.

Comment: @chux Alright, this solution works fine for pbm and pgm files. 
But, how could I adapt the getPixels function, and the whole solution for the .ppm files? these are made of triplets, and each triplet has to go into a position of the rgb[] array. I kinda get what I have to do, but can't really grasp it. Here's an example of a .ppm file: http://pastebin.com/WR0tUDPD

Comment: Just posted something that should work for PPM files -- let me know how it goes! Something to note: the code I posted reads three values at a time into the `rgb[]` array sequentially from position zero going upward to position two. Not sure if this is how you expect the data to be formatted, but this can be accounted for if need be.

Comment: Well, the general idea is there, but somehow I think that the code isn't saving into the matrix right. We passed 6 as the number of expected triplets in a 6 10 .ppm file, and when we print the first triplet, we get 255 0 0
Strange

Comment: Hmmm....what's the exact .ppm file you're attempting to read in, maybe I can see what's going on with the input. Are all the numbers separated by whitespaces only? Or are there tabs in there separating them, too?

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/file/ClxBUOKo/ok_1.html
Only spaces as you can see for yourself

Comment: This is a sample application I just wrote to test the first line of the input of the ppm file you posted. It runs fine and prints out all 6 triplets of pixel entries for that line. http://bit.ly/17krFTd

Comment: Strange... still outputs wrong. Might be a wrong function call, or even a wrong printf. May try reading like a pbm or pgm and then having a for cycle saving each triplet...

Comment: A few questions real quick: does the `getPixels(...)` function still return 6 or does it return a different number? Also, maybe try printing out the exact string you're passing to the function? This little debug statement might help if you place it right after the call to `sscanf(...)`: `printf("\t%p[%d] = %hu\n", currentPixel, currentValue, currentPixel->rgb[currentValue]);`

Comment: ok, we managed to print and save properly. thank you once more!
just having a slight problem with a misbehaving line pointer, about to get fixed. Thank you once more!

Answer (score 2):

So in your file format you have :
row = 6
column = 10

The content is :

R G B R G B

R G B R G B

.

.

.

The row value is not the number of pixels but the number of pixels * 3. So 2 pixels per row.

You store your pixel data as :
`Pixel_t **data;` -> pointer of a pointer of a structure containing a static array of 3 unsigned shorts.

You allocate the data that way :

```
data = malloc(sizeof(Pixel_t*) * row);
```

so now data is an array of pointers of pixel_t of size 'row'

then you allocate each pointer of pixel_t :
data[n] = malloc(sizeof(pixel_t) * column);
so now for each row you basically have an array of size of 3 unsigned short * columns
which makes it 3 times too big because you allocate a pixel for each column.

When you loop through your data you always write to :

```
data[y][x].rgb[0]
```

which is exactly like :

```
*(data[y][x])
```

which makes your structure useless because every-time you access to the first element of your array...
So depending after how you output your data, you will have garbage at the end of you array because you never actually use it since it's 3 times too big.

Also using strtok and strtol and store it to a unsigned short is supposed to work fine in your case so the parsing is not the problem.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = strdup("255 42 25 255 67 89\n");
    char *token = strtok(str, " \n");
    while (token)
    {
        unsigned short val = strtol(token, 0, 0);
        token = strtok(0, " \n");
        printf("%hu\n", val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i cant post a comment, just an answer.
Have you ever tried to use a debugger?? Its made for this purpose. You can step through every line of code and watch the current data of your variables.
See whats happening when you read 0/1 and again when you read other values. Then you can exactly locate the error.

mfg

Just modified your read-function a bit and tried it on my on:

```
static const char filename[] = "ok.pgm";
FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
    token = strtok(line, " \n\t");

    while(token != NULL) {
        //DEBUG("%s", token);
        long int t = strtol(token, NULL, 0);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        printf("%hu ", t);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Output:

```
0
6 10
255
255 255 255 255 10 255
255 255 255 255 20 255
255 255 255 255 30 255
255 255 255 255 40 255
255 255 255 255 50 255
255 255 255 255 60 255
110 255 255 255 70 255
255 100 90 80 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Writing it to an unsigned short provides the same output. It seems you have a problem with your struct...

BTW: Code is bad, just an example if the reading works.

Comment: See what you mean, but still doesn't solve the casting to that structure, and the core dumps

Comment: _Minor_ portability issue: `long int t ... printf("%hu ", t);`  This will not work if sizeof(t) > sizeof(int).  Suggest `printf("%hu ", (unsigned) t));`.

Comment: In OP's code `line` is a pointer and `sizeof line` will be something like 2, 4 or 8.  Might need `len` instead.

Comment: i used long int, because strtol returns it. `unsigned short x = t;` `printf("%hu", x);` gives the same output. There are sure better ways to do it, but the dirty way also works. The casting cant be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the code line:

```
img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0] = (unsigned short) token;
```

You are assigning token which is a pointer to unsigned short. When you cast it you transform pointer to unsigned int. That may looks like a garbage. 
You can fix it in the following way:

```
unsigned int value = (unsigned int)atoi(token);
img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0] = value;
```

In the snippet below loop counter j is always incremented. Thus when reading second large line and accessing pixel array crash happens.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
    char *token;

while(getline(&line, &len, file_stream) != EOF) {
    token = strtok(line, " \n\t");
    j = 0;                                          // <-- FIXED
    while (token != NULL) {
        //DEBUG("%s", token);
        img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0] = strtol(token, NULL, 0);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");
        printf("%hu ", img_struct->pixels[i][j].rgb[0]);
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");   
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't work still. The output this time was:
50 50 50 49 50 and a core dump
(output through alleyoop)

Comment: @Digriz Could you provide input file? Or a couple of numbers from input? I think you can use sscanf() with a format string like %ld %ll or just %d.

Comment: nevermind that link, the website wasn't looking to legit. I'll post the input file contents in the question itself.

Comment: Ok. I think you can use something like that (for "long" lines of the file): sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &col0, &col1, &col2, &col3, &col4, &col5). In case of success return value must be equal to 6. Don't forget to free "line".

Comment: Won't that assume that the characters are already integers? Also, we need a way to save to the structure field "automatically", and also, the file size will vary. Depending on the input it can be 6 or 150

Comment: This is wrong because token is a pointer to a string which *represents* the integer, not the integer itself. OP needs to do something like atoi() or strtol() etc.

Comment: Yep, the token was a necessity, since the pixels in the matrix are separated by spaces, and we only wish to save the pixels to the structure matrix. To do so, we need to ignore the spaces in the reading. Hence, the strtok and token. Also bear in mind, the lines are char* and we somehow have to save each pixel character into an unsigned short array position

Comment: @Digriz I've just checked the part which converts lines - it works just fine: http://pastebin.com/Cr27a32x

Comment: Core dumped... I don't get it.

Comment: @Digriz What about counter "j" in a while loop? Have a look at the output I provided. It is always incremented, but I think it must be set to zero before each launch of while() loop.

Comment: @Digriz I've added this idea to my answer.

Comment: I think we did. This is our last effort:
http://pastebin.com/e2308W6K

As for freeing the line pointer, we shall free the pointer in the main.c, which is where all these functions are called

Comment: j is reset to 0 after each iteration of the second while, which iterates the characters inside each line. The parent while iterates each line itself. Or so it should

Comment: Alright, that code doesn't crash, but... the output's garbage.
It's never the same, random numbers, and the last position of each line is 0.